# Does SWT support gestures in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, gtk, swt, gesture

I'm trying to write an SWT application that uses gestures on Ubuntu.

I'm running 14.04 LTS, using SWT4.4

I've tried the snippet here:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet353.java

on the same machine running Windows 8, and it works fine.   When I try the same code on the same machine in Ubuntu, it doesn't work.

I can verify that my system does support some level of multitouch, as the three-finger gestures supported by Unity work.  I'm not sure if Unity is stripping these out before they get to the swt/gtk code?

Any ideas if this should work?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see it has only been coded for Mac and Windows. Eclipse bug [279884](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279884) describes the original support.

Comment: @greg-449 You can probably make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

AS far as I can see the gesture support has only been coded for Mac and Windows. Although stubs are present in the code for other platforms it does not appear to do anything.

The original Eclipse bug for the update is [279884](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279884).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the original support for gestures in SWT some 5 years ago on Windows and OS X. At the time Ubuntu (or any other Linux, for that matter) didn't support multitouch, but it's possible things have changed since then. I think GTK would need to support multitouch of some kind in order to generate the gesture events.

I no longer work on the SWT. I believe Silenio Quarti at IBM is still the lead for that team, so you might want to contact him.